# Including page number for each page in QGIS Print Layout

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I desperately try to find the function where I can add a page number in the footer or header section of each page of a print layout ...

I added nearly 50 pages and want to add the page number on each without placing a label manually over and over again.

How to solve this?

Comment: Are you using an Atlas? Or are they all individual print layouts? Because if it's an Atlas then it's easy, and if not then the Atlas functionality is going to blow your mind.

Comment: Please tell me you are creating an Atlas.

Comment: I created "New Layout ... " and added further Pages to this with "Add Pages ..." since i just have pages with pictures on it i wanna enumerate for print

Comment: Header and footer are really basic functionality, i would wonder if this is not an easy one .. i think i am just blind^^

Answer (score 7):

To add a page number for each page in the layout, you need to do the following:

- On the first page, use `Add Label` from the Toolbox on the left side.
- From the `Main Properties` on the right side, highlight `Lorem Ipsum`
- There is a <kbd>Dynamic Text</kbd> button under the `Main Properties` text area, click that button and select `Layout Page Number`.
- Adjust the font as you like.
- Finally, copy the text box label, paste it to the other pages, and adjust the location and size. The number of pages will be updated automatically.

[image]

Comment: I explicitly don't want to copy over and over again since i have sometimes several hundreds of page

Comment: @JimPanse I think this requires pyqgis to automate adding page number to hundreds of pages. However, as this answer solved the problem you are facing in principle, it is better to accept it as an answer and ask a new question on how to automate adding page number using pyqgis with an attempt code.

Comment: but the question is about to NOT paste it manually over and over again ... so i think it belongs to this question ... i expected some kind of header/footer as it would be in word documents

Answer (score 3):

You should use an Atlas:
https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/automating_map_creation.html

Then you add a text item to your layout to act as the pagenumber, for the contents click `Insert/Edit Expression`, then under Variables choose either `@atlas_featurenumber` or `@atlas_pagename` whichever works.

See [QGIS Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#variables) for more details.

Comment: I don't think this works ... i have just a map canvas on my first page and on all other pages there are just images i wanna print ... but each page should have a simple page number^^

Comment: If you want to add a dynamic page number that's going to increment automatically for each page, then you need an Atlas. Otherwise you'll have to add it manually to each layout.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following script to place a label (containing the page number) on each page automatically. Don't forget to adjust the layout name accordingly, and set the position, size of font and font family to your liking.

**Important:**
At the end of my answer is another script that will let you easily remove the page labels, this is in case you need to adjust the position/font etc. It saves you having to delete them manually.

```py
# reference to the project
p = QgsProject.instance()

# reference to the layout manager
manager = p.layoutManager()

# get the layout you want to number  ** change this for your layout name **
lyt = manager.layoutByName('my_layout')

# the layout page collection
pc = lyt.pageCollection()

# loop through a range 0-number of pages
for i in range(pc.pageCount()):
    
    # create a new label item
    label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(lyt)

    # create a name for the label object (this is to enable easy removal)
    label.setObjectName('page_label_' + str(i))
    
    # the page number (starting at 1) ** remove `"Page " +` if you want only the number **
    label.setText("Page " + str(i+1))
    
    # change font style and size (optional)
    label.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
    
    # set size of label item 
    label.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(30, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))

    # add the label to your layout
    lyt.addLayoutItem(label)

    # specify location *and page* for label
    label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(10, 10, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters), page=i)
```

[image]

*Note: the page height is shrunk to 50 mm here for display purposes*

---

##### In case you don't know, the steps to run the script:

1. Open the Python console

[image]

2. Open the script editor

[image]

3. Paste the script and press the Run button [image]

[image]

---

##### To remove the automatically placed page labels:

```py
# reference to the project
p = QgsProject.instance()

# reference to the layout manager
manager = p.layoutManager()

# reference to the layout
lyt = manager.layoutByName('my_layout')

# all items in the layout
items = lyt.items()

for item in items:
    # check if the item has 'page_label' in its name
    if hasattr(item, 'objectName') and 'page_label' in item.objectName():
        # if it does, remove it
        lyt.removeItem(item)
```

---

##### References:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/310389/128665
https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383962/128665

Answer (score 2):

Other solution use attribute table.

Advantage : You have only to create and set one feature on your layout then it will be duplicated on every page automatically. You can set same style everywhere and change easily.

Disadvantage : may be it take more time than 50 copy paste.

Steps :

- add an attribute table
- choose a layer where you have more feature than number of page
- set the number of feature to be shown to one
- set the attributes to be shown : erase all the attribute and a column with the formula `@row number`.
- go to "frames" option and set "repeat until finished"
- reduce the size of your table to get the space only for one number, set the border and font to match your will
- then set the number of feature to be show equal to the number of page you have.
- TADA ! Every page will get a page number on the same place as you have set on the first page.

[image]