Consecutive page numbering and custom starting page in QGIS Print Composer
I'm making a catalogue of buildings in QGIS and was wondering how it is possible to assign consecutive page numbers to the atlas in Print Composer plus a custom starting page (e. g page no. 8 instead of 1)?
Each building has two layout pages. I tried @layout_page, but then page numbering begins at "1" for every object.

did you try something like "@layout_page+7" ?

Check this out https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/444287/including-page-number-for-each-page-in-qgis-print-layout

@J.R.: Thank you very much, that did the trick!

@GforGIS: Thank you for your suggestion. However, problem is that page numbering begins anew for every objects, so every object in the catalogue has page numbers 75 and 76.
